# How to do mqtt proxy settings in node?

Tags: node.js, proxy, mqtt, socks

Where do we do the proxy settings for the node [mqtt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) package?
I have a system ready, that needs to get through a SOCKS5 proxy. But where do i do the settings for it?

I was not able to find anything regarding that on the github repo of the package.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you don't actually in the nodejs code.

Have you tried using the socksify application to wrap your nodejs application?

socksify man [page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socksify)

Comment: I'm not able to use it. Can you give an example?

Comment: i have installed `dante-client`. Now i need to wrap the nodejs application.
I dont know that part.
I'm trying this: 
`SOCKS_SERVER=myproxyhost:8888 socksify node client-direct`

Comment: I don't have a socks environment to test in at the moment, but that would have been my approach.